# Is this a Black Hole?

Tags: black-hole, observational-astronomy, coordinate

While researching about galaxies in [Google sky](https://www.google.com/sky/), I came upon a strange area.

**Co-ordinates: 11h 6m 15.0 seconds | -77° 22' 9.8"**

A lot of space around this body is empty, is it possible that the body is a black hole?

The reason I'm asking is because of this image - [image: Black hole]

[This is a photograph and readings are of a real black hole.](http://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2003/perseus/).
It looks like the one on the co-ordinates which I observed with all the dust around it.

**The co-ordinates of the real black hole are - 03h 19m 47.60s | +41° 30' 37.00"**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going by those coordinates, the dark area you're seeing in Google Sky is the [Chamaeleon I cloud](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=Cha%20I). It's a nearby star-forming region that is part of the [Chamaeleon complex](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basic?Ident=Cha%20Complex&submit=SIMBAD%20search) (see also the "Notable features" section of [this article on the Chamaeleon constellation](https://www.universetoday.com/20114/chamaeleon/)). The star nearest to the coordinates you provided is the T Tauri star [TYC 9414-787-1](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=%09TYC%209414-787-1&submit=submit%20id).